# How To Access Javascript Functions from a Custom Kendo UI DataSource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, kendo-ui, angularfire

I'm using Kendo UI with AngularJS 1.x. I'm also using Firebase with the AngularFire library. Because I'm using Firebase, I decided to extend the Kendo UI DataSource which I named kendo.data.FirebaseDataSource.js.

My custom DataSource extends the Kendo UI DataSource and adds custom transports where I would like to access AngularFire's functions.

For example, in the `kendo.data.FirebaseDataSource.js` source, I would like to access AngularFire's $firebaseArray functionality and also any other modules I have created (utility functions, etc) which reside in another file named `my-custom-module.js`, but am having trouble seeing how I could do so.

I tried doing the following, but it (obviously) doesn't work:

```
(function ($, kendo, firebase, $firebaseArray) {
    'use strict';
```

**EDIT**

`kendo.data.FirebaseDataSource.js`

```
(function ($, kendo, firebase, $firebaseArray) {
 'use strict';

 var getCustomer = function () {

    var data = $firebaseArray(firebaseDataService.data);
    var listed = [];

    data.$loaded()
        .then(function(){
            angular.forEach(data, function(data){
                listed.push({
                    "firstName": data.firstName,
                    "lastName": data.lastName
                })
            })
        })


    return listed;
};


var firebaseTransports = {
    read: function (options) {
        var customers = getCustomers();

        options.success(customers);
    }
};

  kendo.data.extensions.FirebaseDataSource = kendo.data.DataSource.extend({
      init: function (options) {

        kendo.data.DataSource.fn.init.call(this, $.extend(true, {}, {      transport: firebaseTransports }, options));
        }
 }); 
})($, kendo, firebase, $firebaseArray);
```

**EDIT 2**

`controllerGrid.js`

```
var fbDataSource = new kendo.data.extensions.FirebaseDataSource({
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "id",
                    fields: {
                        firstName: { type: "string" },
                        lastName: { type: "string" }
                    }
                }
            }
        })

vm.gridOptions = {
    dataSource: fbDataSource
```

Based on the above `controllerGrid.js` source, all I had to do for my Kendo UI Grid widget to use read transport function of the `kendo.data.FirebaseDataSource.js` was to just make a simple reference to the newly created fbDataSource in my gridOptions.

Comment: Can please share fiddle or code snippet which would be helpful to figure out issue.

Comment: @Shrinath Added some source.

Answer (score 0):

$firebaseArray is a concept that only exists within angular as it's an injectable. You can't create a function and pass it in for it to be defined. You'll have to use the native firebase calls instead since those are exposed on the window.

To get the data you will have to use something like this:

```
firebase.database().ref(...).on('value', function(snapshot){
    console.log(snapshot.val());
})
```

You can read the docs on how to use it here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once

If you need to inject, you'll have to make your kendoUi in a directive and then you can inject that way instead.

```
.directive(..., function(){
    return {
        ...
        controller: function($firebaseArray){
            //kendo code here
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I would like to inject, but how would I access this from my other functions, especially from the Kendo UI Grid widget? I have added more source code for reference.